# C# filter list, All or with given value

Tags: c#, list, filter, enums

In my list, each list item consist of 2 properties
ProductCategory
ProductId

In my items there is not 0 valued neither ProductId nor ProductCategory

If client sends me as
ProductId = 0
Product Category = 0

So must return all items in the list

If client sends me as
ProductId = 2
ProductCategory = 0
I must return
Only 2 id product in all of the ProductCategory

Or

```
ProductId=0
ProductCategory=2
I must return all of the products in 2 id ProductCategory..
```

Or
ProductId=3
ProductCategory=2

```
 Return productId = 2 in product category 2
```

How can implement this code without using if else blocks? I have achieved this with 4 if/else blocks but I want to learn is there any better way

Comment: Can you show us code where you achieved this logic using 4 if/else conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve with the `.Where` statement as below:

Conditions:

1. Match `productId` with 0 or `product.ProductId` equals to `productId`.
2. Match `productCategory` with 0 or `product.ProductCategory` equals to `productCategory`.
3. Must fulfill both conditions 1 & 2.

```cs
var products = PRODUCT_LIST
    .Where(x => (productId == 0 || x.ProductId == productId)
        && (productCategory == 0 || x.ProductCategory == productCategory))
    .ToList();
```